# LinkedIn API and Long-Form Post

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I am looking for a way to automatically publish my Wordpress blog articles to the LinkedIn publishing platform as [Long-Form Post](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/47445?lang=en).

I've been looking at the LinkedIn Rest API doc but couldn't find a way to do it (it only explains how to share a short post with an external link). Is there a way to do it and if so can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedIn does not presently expose an API to submit content to the publishing platform.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I just wanted to be sure. It's a weird strategy to lock the platform that way... Let's hope they'll get more open in the future!